# Raspberry pi のfstabの修正方法

Tags: raspberry-pi

ラズパイをCIFS互換アプリのsambaで、ファイル共有サーバーとして使おうとしていました。
そこまでは正常に動作をしていました。
それから、起動時に自動でマウントをする方法を設定する箇所にて↓

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
fstabファイルのetx4の部分(一番下にあるUUDIの箇所のマウント先の後ろにあるLinuxのファイルシステム名の指定)
ext4に書き違えました。
その後、ラズパイを起動できず、その後問題箇所を書き換え(ext4→etx4),reboot したのですがやはり起動しないようです。

どなたかご教授よろしくお願いします

ちなみにラズパイ上のエラーはこちらです↓↓↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
. . .
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、自分のパソコンのバーチャル環境(centOS7)からマウントを試みたのですが、下記のようになるため手詰まりしてます。

mount point does not exist

また、mtabが壊れているのでマウントできないのかと思うので、mtabを直す方法もよろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
どなたかおたすけください。

Comment: 復旧方法については詳しくないので具体的には回答できませんが、参考にした書籍に記してある `etx4` は **誤植** かと思います。正しくは `ext4` なはず。

Answer (score 0):

起動時に ファイルシステムがマウントが失敗するとデフォルトではエマージェンシーモードに移行してしまいます。 `/etc/fstab` の `defaults` の部分を `nofail` を設定するとどうでしょうか？

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxx  /var/samba   ext4  defaults,nofail  0  0
```

Comment: 確認遅れました!試してみます!ありがとうございます!